# Redraw performance issues - where to implement shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble deciding where to add a `shouldComponentUpdate` method. The image below should give a sufficient idea of the structure of my page:

[image]

The issue is that whenever I type in the `TextField` (a controlled field), the state update is causing the entire `RecordManager` to re-render. And if there are 50+ `Record` elements, this is obviously a huge performance hit.

I've temporarily solved this by adding the following method in `RecordManager`:

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.newRecordName === nextState.newRecordName;
  }
```

The relevant `TextField`:

```
  <TextField
    style={styles.textField}
    id="newRecordName"
    hintText={newRecordHintText}
    onChange={this.recordNameChange}
    onKeyDown={this.recordNameKeyDown}
  />
```

My solution seems like a bit of a hack. Is it not better to put the `shouldComponentUpdate` in the `Record` component? Although then it seems I'd have to check for a whole bunch of different cases, e.g.:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.props.ratings !== nextProps.ratings) return true;
  if (this.props.updatedAt !== nextProps.updatedAt) return true;
  // potentially 3-4 more fields
  return false;
}
```

What's the ideal solution here?

Per request below, other relevant code in `RecordManager`:

```
  recordNameChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ newRecordName: target.value });
  };

  recordNameKeyDown = (event) => {
    const keyCode = keycode(event);

    if (keyCode === 'enter') {
      this.addRecord();
    } else if (keyCode === 'esc') {
      this.cancelAddRecord();
    }
  };
```

`RecordManager` state:

```
this.state = {
  dialogMessage: '',
  newRecordName: '',
  viewMode: localStorage.getItem('userSettingsViewMode') ||
    viewModes.LIST,
};
```

Comment: Using your solution, all your `Record`s will still be re-rendered each time one of them changes. In theory, you only need the one that changed to be re-rendered. So it is not really that your solution is a hack, but more that I don't think you really solved your performance issue.

Comment: Can you provide the content of `this.recordNameChange` and `recordNameKeyDown` and maybe a sample of your `RecordManager.state`? I have trouble understanding how is your first `shouldComponentUpdate` working.

Comment: @Roque Not according to React DevTools. With my hack solution, when I type, the `Record`s do not re-render. That was the problem I was trying to solve, and it worked.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my post in a few.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, all your records are included in your `RecordManager`. Your first `shouldComponentUPdate` prevents this `RecordMananager`, as a whole, to be uselessly re-rendered. But if you do not have a `shouldComponenentUpdate` on its children, when you re-render the `RecordManager`, you also re-render all of its children even if only one has actually changed.

Comment: @Roque Updated my question.

Comment: And you're right, if something else were to cause `RecordManager` to re-render, then all of the records would be uselessly rendered. The hacky fix above just fixes the issue of all the `Record`s re-rendering on every keystroke in the `TextField`.

Comment: @Roque So maybe the solution is to just have `shouldComponentUpdate` in `Record`, and check if any props or state responsible for displaying info change.. and return `true` if that's the case.

Comment: Where is stored the data of all your records? It seems that only the very last one is stored in your `RecordManager`.

Comment: In a Mongo DB, served as props to `RecordManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect case which is solve by something called "Pure render":

You can shallow compare the props as they come in to see if they have changed

React offers an add on to achieve this:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/shallow-compare.html

---

**Update**

React now offers a varient called a [PureComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) which does the job of implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` with shallow comparison logic.

Comment: I wound up putting this on a couple components inside `RecordManager` and it greatly improved performance. Thanks!